# How to filter a many-to-many field (not primary key) in a Django queryset for serialization with Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Given two models with a many-to-many relationship between them.

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name="Title")

class Content(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, verbose_name="Author")
    collection = models.ManyToManyField(Collection, verbose_name="Collection")
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name="Public")
```

How can I filter the `Collection` to only list `Content` where `public == True`?

`serializers.py`:

```
class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ["author"]


class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content_set = ContentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content_set",
        ]
```

`view.py`:

```
class CollectionViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Collection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CollectionSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Collection.objects.filter(content_set__enable=True)  # Not working as expected
```

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Foo",
        "content_set": [
            {
                "author": "Jane Doe"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing a [related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) as model field which won't work. As I can see you are trying to do reverse many to many relationship the correct way to do this is like this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#:%7E:text=Reverse%20m2m) (please find **Reverse m2m** in the docs it will redirect to section with example):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Collection.objects.filter(content__public=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
return Collection.objects.filter(content__public=True).distinct()
```